# Why does DominantColors keep shuffling the order of the results?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, color

This graphic is produced by running `DominantColors` (new in *Mathematica* 9) with different values, using the Lena image as the source:

[image: lenna strips]

Each row is a list of the dominant colours in an image, when asking for between 2 and 60. However I'm surprised that the order of the colors keeps changing: why would the order depend on how many you asked for?

Have I done something daft in my code? Or I have failed to grasp something obvious in the online documentation? (Either is likely.)

```
With[{l = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]},
    Graphics[
     Table[{colorList = DominantColors[l, d];
       {Table[{
            colorList[[x]], 
            Rectangle[{x - 1, 10 - d},{x, 10 - (d + 0.7)}]
              },
            {x, 1, Length@colorList}]}}, 
     {d, 2, 60}]]
]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not just the order, the actual colours themselves can change depending on how many you ask for. Sometimes, these colours might not even be in your image! The reason is because `DominantColors` does a *clustering* operation and returns the mean of the `n` clusters in the LAB space and doesn't necessarily pick the colours that appear *common* to the eye (although, they coincide more often than not).

To see what I mean, consider the following example:

```
img = Image[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red, Pink, Cyan} /. 
    RGBColor -> ({{##}} &) // Transpose, ImageSize -> {300, 50}]
```

[image]

```
Image[{List @@@ DominantColors[img, #]}, 
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, 50}] & /@ Range@7 // Column
```

[image]

Until you get to 5 dominant colours, there's always one colour in the list that's not in the original image.

So to answer your question, just as you might expect a clustering operation on some random data to give you a centroid that's *not* an actual point in your data, `DominantColors` might return colours that are not in your image (but are close). This is the reason why you see some shuffling of the orders (the centroid for 2 clusters need not necessarily be the same for 3), although you can see that in general, they are roughly in the same normalized position.

Comment: Just great, thanks for this exemplary answer. I suppose the lack of this level of information in the online docs led me to jump to the wrong conclusions about what the function was doing...

Answer (score 4):

You could always sort them manually

```
dc[n_] := List @@@ DominantColors[img, n]
Column[Image[{Sort[dc[#]]}, ImageSize -> 10*#] & /@ Range[3, 40]
       ,Left, 0]
```

[image]

Might want to fiddle some with what to sort by (second argument to `Sort`)

**EDIT:**

```
clist[sort_, name_] := Rasterize@Column[
   {name}~Join~
    (Image[{Sort[dc[#], sort]}, ImageSize -> 10*#] & /@ 
      Range[3, 40]),
   Left,
   0]
lst = clist[#1, #2] & @@ # & /@ {
    {Min[#1] < Min[#2] &, "Min"},
    {Max[#1] < Max[#2] &, "Max"},
    {Mean[#1] < Mean[#2] &, "Mean"},
    {Norm[#1] < Norm[#2] &, "Two Norm"},
    {OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &, "Default"}
    };
ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image]

If there's a way to sort it rainbowish I believe that could be good

Comment: You can sort "rainbowish" if you `ColorConvert` to `"HSB"`.

Comment: @ssch Flashy! Thanks...